# inserting Silverlight app into Symfony 1.4 layout

Tags: php, silverlight, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm having difficulties with inserting Silverlight app as a part of website (for example as a promo-banner). I use code generated from PROJECTNAMEtestPage.html.

file `/apps/frontend/modules/static/templates/gameSuccess.php`:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="640px" height="480px">
        <param name="source" value="snake.xap" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&amp;v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

`snake.xap` is a name of my SL file. And where should I put it in `/web` directory of Symfony project?
FireBug gave me some info about expected file location:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - `http://192.168.56.101/frontend_dev.php/static/snake.xap`

Comment: For `/web/snake.xap` use `value="/snake.xap"`

Comment: @1ed - thanks, that was the issue! What a dumb question I asked :). Could you post that as a full answer? I'll accept that and topic will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start with a `/` so change `value="snake.xap"` to `value="/snake.xap"` if the file location is `/web/snake.xap`.